# what does “got takes on” mean?

Tags: phrases

I've read this phrase in an aritcle about 2016 Oscar prediction.
The original passage is as follow.

"Same goes for which of the annual slew of big name biopics will be the 2016 answer to "The Theory of Everything" or "The Imitation Game" (or on the flipside, the 2016 answer to "Unbroken" or "Big Eyes"). **We've got takes on** the likes of Steve Jobs (played by Michael Fassbender), screenwriter Dalton Trumbo (Bryan Cranston), book editor Max Perkins (Colin Firth), transgender artist Lili Elbe (Eddie Redmayne, gunning for Oscar number two), infamous criminal Whitey Bulger (Johnny Depp, gunning to gain our respect back), news anchor Dan Rather (Robert Redford) and singer Miles Davis (Don Cheadle), just to name a male dominated few."

Comment: Please can you make it clear which parts you have written and which part have been written by someone else.

Comment: [TAKE](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/take[noun]) Noun 4: - a distinct treatment of something (as a story or a play) *despite its contemporary setting, this take on King Lear isn't particularly novel or insightful*.

Comment: See also ODO's definition of 'take on', under the word [take](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/take) (noun, def 1.1)

Answer (score 2):

"[To have a take on X](http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/whats+your+take+on+that.html)" (www.usingenglish.com)  means "to have an opinion or point of view on X".

**Examples**

"What is your take on the recent drugs scandal."

"John and Jane:- What are your takes on the political situation in Uganda?"

Comment: @Josh61 - I don't mind your edit but how specifically does that URL answer the question? Could you give the exact page that covers "have a take on" then I'm happy to accept the change. Thanks

Comment: "Take", of course, can also mean a short video clip.  Probably not given the above context, but it's possible.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK - that's the link you should provide to further  support your answer!  just make a little effort! As for my link...it relates to the example your are making.."What is your take on..."

Comment: @Sorry but your URL doesn't give any support either. Just pointing to a general site about English achieves nothing. You could make a comment or provide your own answer. To avoid a discussion, I'll raise this on Meta.

Comment: ***Take*** : An interpretation or assessment, as of an event: *The mayor was asked for her take on the judge's decision.* http://www.thefreedictionary.com/take+on There is nothing wrong with my link, it actually supports your answer.

Comment: The link you have just given in your comment supports my argument. The one you gave in your edit does not. It just goes to the main page of the site.

Comment: Really? sorry. It should give the meaning of "What's your take on?" check here please http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/whats+your+take+on+that.html

Comment: I just meant to provide a link to support your answer. Reference links are important in asnwers.

Comment: Ah - I see, sorry I looked at the link at the bottom and missed the one at the top. I'll let my Meta question stand because I'm still interested in the answer. I think a link should be explicit where possible in case the original site disappears. The way you wrote it, it looked as though my *examples* came from the site. I have now re-edited to reflect the actual situation.

Comment: How the edit was formatted by Josh is pretty standard around here, but what I sometimes do is write, Source: [name: website/reference]( link to actual page).